# Show that the genus of the projective curve $x^n_1 = x_2x^{n-1}_0 - x^n_2$ is $(n-1)(n-2)/2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-geometry

Suppose that we have a curve $X \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ given by $x^n_1 = x_2x^{n-1}_0 - x^n_2$ .  **How do we show that the curve has genus $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ (whenever the curve is smooth).**

I should use the fact that the sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{F}(X) \stackrel{\iota}{\to} \mathcal{F}(U_1) \oplus \mathcal{F}(U_2)  \stackrel{\delta}{\to} \mathcal{F}( U_1 \cap U_2)
$$
is exact. Where $\mathcal{F} =\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for some divisor $D$  on $X$ and $\{ U_1, U_2\}$ an affine cover of $X$ (however, $X$ should be irreducible I think).  Moreover $\iota(f) =( f|_{U_1}, f|_{U_2})$  and $ \delta(f_1,f_2) = f_1|_{U_1 \cap U_2} - f_2|_{U_1 \cap U_2}$ .

There is a hint: compute the cokernel of $\delta$ using bases for the infinite-dimensional vector spaces $\mathcal{O}_X(X_1)$, $\mathcal{O}_X(X_2)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(X_{12})$ that are as simple as possible. (As a sanity check on your computation: the kernel of $\delta$ should be one-dimensional!)

Any help on how to proceed or how to solve it would really be appreciated!

Comment: Well, what do you know about the two definitions of genus? This will let you connect the problem to the hint. As far as the computation, you have to sit down and do it - is there a point where you're getting stuck?

Comment: at this point  our definition of the genus is the cokernel of delta

Comment: Did you try computing the Hilbert polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, considering the general open cover of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and setting $X_{i}=X\cap D(x_{i}) \ \ (i=0,1,2)$ it can be easily seen (by writing down the equation) that $X_{1}\subseteq X_{2}$ and so $\{X_{0},X_{2}\}$ is an open covering of $X$. Therefore, the genus of $X$ can be computed by the sheaf exact sequence

\begin{equation*}
    0\longrightarrow {\cal O}_{X}(0)(X)\longrightarrow {\cal O}_{X}(0)(X_{0})\oplus
{\cal O}_{X}(0)(X_{2})\longrightarrow {\cal O}_{X}(0)(X_{0}\cap X_{2}).
\end{equation*}

But there is a (natural) isomorphism of sheaves of ${\cal O}_{X}$-modules ${\cal O}_{X}(0)\xrightarrow{\sim}{\cal O}_{X}$ and so we may compute the genus of $X$ by computing the
dimension of the cokernel of the map $\delta$ in the following exact sequence:

\begin{equation*}
    0\longrightarrow {\cal O}_{X}(X)\longrightarrow {\cal O}_{X}(X_{0})\oplus
{\cal O}_{X}(X_{2})\overset{\delta}{\longrightarrow} {\cal O}_{X}(X_{02}),
\end{equation*}

where $X_{02}:=X_{0}\cap X_{2}$ and $\delta(f_{0},f_{2})=f_{0}|_{X_{02}}-f_{2}|_{X_{02}}$
for each $f_{0}\in{\cal O}(X_{0})$ and $f_{2}\in{\cal O}(X_{2})$.

We will compute
$\dim_{k}(\mathrm{coker}\delta)$ by precisely finding a basis of $\mathrm{coker}\delta$.

Note that by dehomogenization we  have that the isomorphisms of varieties
\begin{equation*}
    X_{0}\cong Z(f_{0}) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ X_{2}\cong Z(f_{2}),
\end{equation*}
where $f_{0}=x_{01}^{n}-x_{02}+x_{02}^{n}\in k[x_{01},x_{02}]$ and
$f_{2}=x_{21}^{n}-x_{20}^{n-1}+1\in k[x_{20},x_{21}]$. Hence, we have that
\begin{equation*}
    {\cal O}_{X}(X_{0})\cong k[x_{01},x_{02}]/(f_{0}) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ 
    {\cal O}_{X}(X_{2})\cong k[x_{20},x_{21}]/(f_{2}).
\end{equation*}

Before we start, observe that a system of generators for ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{0})$ is

\begin{equation*}
    T_{0}=\{x_{01}^{i}x_{02}^{j}:0\leq i<n,j\geq 0\}
\end{equation*}

and for ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{2})$ is

\begin{equation}
    T_{2}=\{x_{20}^{i}x_{21}^{j}:i\geq 0,0\leq j<n\}
\end{equation}

The above follows directly from the fact that in ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{0})$ we have the relation $x_{01}^{n}=x_{02}-x_{02}^{n}$ and in ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{2})$ the relation $x_{21}^{n}=x_{20}^{n-1}-1$. Hence, $\mathrm{im}\delta$ is generated by the image $T$ of
$T_{0}\cup T_{2}$ under the map $\delta$.

We now proceed with the construction of a basis for $\mathrm{coker}\delta$. We have that
\begin{equation*}
    {\cal O}_{X}(X_{02})\cong k[x_{01}.x_{02},x_{20}]/(f_{0},x_{02}x_{20}-1),
\end{equation*}
i.e. ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{02})$ results by inverting $x_{02}(=x_{2}/x_{0})$ in ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{0})$. Therefore, it can be readily seen that taking into consideration the relations in ${\cal O}_{X})(X_{02})$ and the generating set $T$ of $\mathrm{im}\delta$ the set

\begin{equation*}
    S=\{x_{01}^{i}x_{20}^{j}:0\leq i<n,j>0\}.
\end{equation*}

generates ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{02})$ and so also $\mathrm{coker}\delta$,
$S\cap T=\emptyset$ and is linearly independent in ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{02})$.
Now by considering the other relation $x_{21}=x_{01}x_{20}$ in ${\cal O}_{X}(X_{02})$
it can (again) be readily seen that we may further refine $S$ into

\begin{equation*}
    S'=\{x_{01}^{i}x_{20}^{j}:0\leq i<n,0<j<i\},
\end{equation*}

which has cardinality $|S'|=(n-1)(n-2)/2$ and its image forms a basis of $\mathrm{coker}\delta$.